# addEventListener() and createElement()

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, createelement

I would like to ask how I can execute addEventListner() to the element that I created with createElement().

I have a add button in my project and when I click it, it will create an another add button, and keep making add button with the button.

but my first button works and keep creating new buttons, but the other buttons do not do anything.

Here is my code.

```
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.button');
const total = document.getElementById('amount-total');



addBtn.addEventListener('click', addButton);


let counter = 0;
function addButton(){
    counter++;

    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = 'new-container' + counter;
    total.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, total)


    let createBtn = document.createElement('button');
    createBtn.innerHTML = '+';
    createBtn.className = 'button';

    newDiv.appendChild(createBtn);
}
```

but it didn't work so I tried querySelectorAll instead.

```
const addBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
addBtns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', addButton))
```

but still the original one works but other one don't.
I am new to javascript, and really appreciate if you could help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: In the first example it adds an event listener just to the first instance of `.button`, as you imagined: the second will work on buttons already in the DOM, but if you create them on-the-fly it won’t work because they don’t exists when the script is loaded; try adding the event listener to the `event.target` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener

Comment: Attach the original button listener to `total.parentNode` instead of the button. Then in the listener, check, if a button was clicked, and if it was, then create the elements.

Comment: Thanks guys! and the logic really helped me to understand why the second button does not work in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should add the `addEventListener('click', addButton)` in the function `addbutton()`. In this way you also create a new button every time you clicked an added button. Your code:

```
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.button');
const total = document.getElementById('amount-total');



addBtn.addEventListener('click', addButton);


let counter = 0;

function addButton() {
  counter++;

  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.id = 'new-container' + counter;
  total.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, total)


  let createBtn = document.createElement('button');
  createBtn.innerHTML = '+';
  createBtn.addEventListener('click', addButton); //added this line here!
  createBtn.className = 'button';

  newDiv.appendChild(createBtn);
}
```

Hope this helps your understanding.

Comment: Hi Ken, I added addEventListener() inside the function, and it worked really great! Thank you so much!!